# What is $this here in this JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at JavaScript that produces:

[image]

The related code is

[image]

My question is, what does $this refer to?  Just the keyword "this" I understand, but $this? There doesn't seem to be any jQuery around.

Thanks for any illumination.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript "this" keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: same as any other variable - it could be named `someVarName`. nothing special about it.

Comment: @LuckySoni ...how is that a duplicate?

Comment: Btw, I love the (probably unintended) pun in the title "What is $this here in **this** JavaScript?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with the Google ["jstemplate"](http://code.google.com/p/google-jstemplate/wiki/TemplateProcessingInstructionReference) mechanism.

From that page:

> $this: $this refers to the JsEvalContext data object used in processing the current node. So in the above example we could substitute $this.end for end without changing the meaning of the jscontent expression. This may not seem like a very useful thing to do in this case, but there are other cases in which $this is necessary. If the JsEvalContext contains a value such as a string or a number rather than an object with named properties, there is no way to retrieve the value using object-property notation, and so we need $this to access the value.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be prefixed with $ due to using the Google JSTemplate API.

More information here: http://code.google.com/p/google-jstemplate/wiki/HowToUseJsTemplate

Answer (score 1):

That is not javascript, it’s HTML.

What you see is a custom element property called `jsdisplay` that has the value of `$this.something`. What it actually **does** is very hard to give an exact answer to, but as some other pointed out it’s probably used internally in google templating.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the **js** display attribute is used for JS :P

Comment: @Doorknob maybe, but the entire question is based on a false assumption that the code is javascript. It might as well be SEO-bogus HTML or microformats, you can’t tell for sure.

Answer (score 1):

[Pointy is right for this specific case.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20412743/1825094)

**To clear up the confusion about $ in JavaScript:**

In JavaScript the dollar sign ($) in variable names is treated like a-z, A-Z and underscore (_).

The variable you are looking at, could have been named anything else. `$this` is no special JS keyword. The developers of jstemplate could have named it `foo` if they wanted to. Or like they did, something similar to `this`, like `_this` or `self`.